# How to use Selenium webdriver for web application demo?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-applications

How to use Selenium webdriver for web application demo? Need to pause/resume, change speed (slow down, speed up), etc.

A video can be recorded. But can webdriver serves the purpose directly?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Pause/Resume,  Speed +/-
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can webdriver code be run by user by clicking a link from product page?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no such options (pause/Resume, Speed +/-) with in WebDriver it self. You have to relay on the tool which you are using for the development.

Yes, you can trigger the selenium scripts from a web page which is little complex.